# SSH connection fails when registering a gitlab-runner on an ec2 instance with ansible

Tags: ansible, gitlab-ci-runner

This is the ansible -vvvv output when I want to register a gitlab-runner with the same ansible module:

```
fatal: [EC2-IP]: FAILED! => changed=false 
  module_stderr: |-
    OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017
    debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
    debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 58: Applying options for *
    debug1: auto-mux: Trying existing master
    debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
    debug2: mux_client_hello_exchange: master version 4
    debug3: mux_client_forwards: request forwardings: 0 local, 0 remote
    debug3: mux_client_request_session: entering
    debug3: mux_client_request_alive: entering
    debug3: mux_client_request_alive: done pid = 31106
    debug3: mux_client_request_session: session request sent
    debug1: mux_client_request_session: master session id: 2
    debug3: mux_client_read_packet: read header failed: Broken pipe
    debug2: Received exit status from master 1
    Shared connection to EC2-IP closed.
  module_stdout: |-
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1573211018.16-273297078504854/AnsiballZ_gitlab_runner.py", line 114, in <module>
        _ansiballz_main()
      File "/home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1573211018.16-273297078504854/AnsiballZ_gitlab_runner.py", line 106, in _ansiballz_main
        invoke_module(zipped_mod, temp_path, ANSIBALLZ_PARAMS)
      File "/home/user/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1573211018.16-273297078504854/AnsiballZ_gitlab_runner.py", line 49, in invoke_module
        imp.load_module('__main__', mod, module, MOD_DESC)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 235, in load_module
        return load_source(name, filename, file)
      File "/usr/lib/python3.6/imp.py", line 170, in load_source
        module = _exec(spec, sys.modules[name])
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 618, in _exec
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
      File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
      File "/tmp/ansible_gitlab_runner_payload_igdyaz51/__main__.py", line 389, in <module>
      File "/tmp/ansible_gitlab_runner_payload_igdyaz51/__main__.py", line 354, in main
    TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'email'
  msg: |-
    MODULE FAILURE
    See stdout/stderr for the exact error
  rc: 1
```

And this is the part of the playbook that fails:

```
- name: Register runner
  gitlab_runner:
    url: https://git.myurl.com/
    api_token: {{ correct_token }}
    registration_token: "{{ runners_token.stdout }}"
    description: instance
    state: present
    active: True
    tag_list: ['tag1']
    run_untagged: False
    locked: False
  register: configuration
```

both the api and registration tokens are correct and the url is correct to, checked with debug.
This registration worked before, but when I restarted the instance, It failed and I can't get to fix it, I tried another instance and this is the same output.

I also deployed all the keys to the repository and all other tasks work just fine.

I also installed all the dependencies such us, boto, botocore, boto3, python-gitlab...

Comment: Also, I can register just fine manually but then after I run the playbook again I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue, seems to be some version incompatibility:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/65189

Using an old version of python-gitlab worked for me:

`python-gitlab<1.13`